# Enable button when item is selected from dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have a  form with a dropdown list and button

```
 <button id="primaryTextButton" class="k-primary delete-button">Submit</button>
```

I would like to enable button only when an item is selected from list.

How can I do this?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ukC/73/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M3ukC/74/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete Jquery code :-

```
(function () {
$('#primaryTextButton').prop('disabled',true);   //disable button on page load
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        allowCustomValues: false,
        testData: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Apple'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Banana'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Orange'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Kiwi'
            }]
        })
    });

    $('.combobox').kendoComboBox({
        dataSource: viewModel.testData,
        autoBind: false,
        dataTextField: 'name',
        dataValueField: 'id',
        suggest: true,
        placeholder: 'Select a Fruit',
        change: function (e) {
            $('#primaryTextButton').prop('disabled',false);   //enable button here
            var cmb = this;
            // selectedIndex of -1 indicates custom value
            if (cmb.selectedIndex < 0 && !viewModel.allowCustomValues) {
                cmb.value(null); // or set to the first item in combobox
            }
        }
    });

    kendo.bind('#example', viewModel);


})();
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ukC/74/)

Comment: When an item is removed in dropdown after selection, button is still enabled.

Comment: @Polppan..sorry i didn't get you ... the fiddle working just fine as per your requirement..what else do you want???

Comment: If an item is selected button is enabled. But if I unselect an item  after selection, button is still enabled.

Comment: @Polppan...then in that case there must be some close event or so in kendoComboBox that you have to find yourself because i have never used kendoComboBox and place disable button code in that event..

Comment: Ok. Thanks and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling and disabling of button can done in "change" event of combo-box itself. Considering that button is disabled at the beginning:

```
$('.combobox').kendoComboBox({
    change: selectionChanged,
    // other properties of combo-box
});


function selectionChanged(e){
            if(this.value() != null || this.value() != ""){
              $('#button').prop('disabled',false);
            }
            else{
            $('#button').prop('disabled',true);  
            }
          }
```

Hope this helps.